# Use a same Arraylist in two methods

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
public class ObjetTWS {

    String nom;
    List<String> jobAmont = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> jobAval = new ArrayList<String>();
    String type;

    public ArrayList<ObjetTWS> dependances;

    public ObjetTWS() {

    }

    public ObjetTWS(String p_nom, String p_type, String p_jobAmont,
            String p_jobAval) {

        ObjetTWS obj = new ObjetTWS();

        obj.nom = p_nom;
        obj.jobAmont.add(p_jobAmont);
        obj.jobAval.add(p_jobAval);
        obj.type = p_type;

        dependances = new ArrayList<ObjetTWS>();
        dependances.add(obj);

    }

    public void ajouterJob(String p_nom, String p_jobAmont, String p_jobAval) {

    }

}
```

In ObjetTWS(...), I fill my list with the objects ObjetTWS. The objects are created with the values of p_nom,p_type,... from ObjetsTWS(...). I need after take back this list in ajouterJob to add some other information. But I have the list dependances with just the first object. How I can take all the list ?

Comment: Rephrase your question.

Comment: I want to use my arraylist dependances in ajouterJob(...). How I can do that ?

Comment: Do you mean to say that whatever instances of `ObjectTWS` is created in the JVM it should be added to the `dependancies` List

Comment: In ObjetTWS(...), I fill my list with the objects ObjetTWS. The objects are created with the values of p_nom,p_type,... from ObjetsTWS(...). I need after take back this list in ajouterJob to add some other information. But I have the list dependances with just the first object. How I can take all the list ?

Comment: where is your code for adding other objects?

Comment: I just parse a file and take information from this

Comment: Where is your code for parsing the file? the problem may be there as it may not be adding the data to the `dependancies`

Answer (score 1):

In your code every `ObjectTWS` has it's own `dependances` list. So it seems logically that your list always contains only one element. If you need a list of all objects, make `dependances` variable static.

Comment: That's one way... otherwise the ArrayList dependances could be declared and used in the main class where ObjetTWS is being used

Comment: It changes nothing. In ObjetTWS a have the list of all object. I check with :        ListIterator<ObjetTWS> itr = dependances.listIterator();

 while (itr.hasNext())
 {
 System.out.println("  Arraylist : " + itr.next().nom); }                              And only the first objet in ajouterJob() with the same test

Comment: Using static should be the **last** resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method's signature.

```
public void ajouterJob(List<ObjetTWS> myVariable) {

}
```

After that call this method with your variable..

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use my arraylist dependances in ajouterJob(...). How I can do that ?

```
public class ObjetTWS {
   public List<ObjectTWS> dependances = new ArrayList<>();

  public void ajouterJob(String p_nom, String p_jobAmont, String p_jobAval) {
     // use dependances here
     dependances.add(/*stuff*/);
    }
}
```

---

Pretty sure you want to have something different. Just comment on this answer.

---

```
public ObjetTWS(String p_nom, String p_type, String p_jobAmont,
                String p_jobAval) {

        ObjetTWS obj = new ObjetTWS();

        obj.nom = p_nom;
        obj.jobAmont.add(p_jobAmont);
        obj.jobAval.add(p_jobAval);
        obj.type = p_type;

        //dependances = new ArrayList<ObjetTWS>();
                      ^ delete this line
        dependances.add(obj);

    }

    public void ajouterJob(String p_nom, String p_jobAmont, String p_jobAval) {
        dependances.get(/* the index you need*/);
    }
```

Comment: I want to do this. But I don't take back the Arraylist completed from ObjetTWS(...).

Comment: @Subas Sorry, I don't understand you at all. Do you want to return the `ArrayList` in the method?

Comment: I want to use the Arraylist in ajouterJob and this arraylist is fill in ObjetTWS()

Answer (score 0):

your list will containt at every time only just one ObjetTWS object created in your constructor, this statement in your constructor is false :  `ObjetTWS obj  = new ObjetTWS();`

your constructor should look like this :

```
public ObjetTWS(String p_nom, String p_type,String p_jobAmont,String p_jobAval){

   this.nom = p_nom;
   this.jobAmont.add(p_jobAmont);
   this.jobAval.add(p_jobAval);
   this.type = p_type;

  dependances.add(obj);

}
```

for your `dependences`  list you should use a class variable to be shared between all your `ObjetTWS`  instances and every time you create a new `ObjetTWS` object you add it to your list , some thing like this :

```
public static ArrayList<ObjetTWS> dependances;
```